# Sass + CSS3 + CSS Comb in Sublime Text 3

Tags: css, sass, sublimetext3

I'm trying to find my perfect workflow with CSS and Sass files in Sublime Text 3. What I need is:

1. Sass files syntax highlighting
2. CSS Comb to order properties alphabetically on saving
3. Property and value hinting, using the newest CSS3 data

Sass highlighting can be achieved by installing [Sass package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sass).

I also managed to set CSS Comb on saving, like this:

```
{
    "on_pre_save_language": [
        {
            "command": "css_comb"
        }
    ]
}
```

CSS3 hints are wonderfully delivered by [CSS3 package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS3), but Sass package seems to provide its own ones and they are not satisfactory.

There are other Sass packages, but they break CSS Comb entirely.

How can all these requirements be combined? Can I disable hints from Sass package and make Sublime use CSS3 ones instead? Or maybe should I do it other way?

Comment: Instead of CSS Comb I highly recommend stylelint + stylefmt combo. Also most of these things are built-in in VSCode. If you really have to use Sublime Text 3, I recommend our setup, it might help you: https://github.com/digitoimistodude/sublime-settings - Working vscode-settings with your requirements can be found here: https://github.com/ronilaukkarinen/vscode-settings

Answer (score 0):

I'm using package : SASS and SASS Solutions. Also using SASS as my file type in bottom right setting. Package whitespace also good !, to make your code tidier.

Answer (score -3):

This is the official website for installing Sublime Text packages. Run the Python command that it tells you to in the Sublime console to allow for package installation (all the directions for this are in the following link).
    https://packagecontrol.io/installation

Then, hit CMD + SHIFT + P, and type in Package Control: Install Package. Click on the correct dropdown option and type in Sass. This will install the Sass package for you and all Sass files you open will have auto-syntax highlighting once you restart Sublime.

Comment: The question is **not** how to install a package, come on.